# ProcessException: Process exited abnormally: Command line invocation: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -list

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, cocoapods

There was an error when I try to build my flutter project for iOS. I had errors about the cocopoad, I deleted Podfile, podfile.lock, Pod and .workspace project. Then I run `flutter run` It created Podfile and I run `pod install--allow-root` after all I tried restarting IDE and run application on the simulator It run. But when I run application on VSCode using `flutter run` it shows this error:

---

ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
Command line invocation:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -list

User defaults from command line:
IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

xcodebuild: error: Unable to read project 'Runner.xcodeproj'.
Reason: Project /Users/Zer01onE/Desktop/flutter/deliveryapp/ios/Runner.xcodeproj cannot be
opened because it is missing its project.pbxproj file.
Command: xcrun xcodebuild -list

---

Could you help me please.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the project directory, right-click on project.pbxproj->Git->Rollback.
This solved my problem.