# iOS App was building fine yesterday, but it won't build today

Tags: ios, flutter, build

Yesterday I pushed my first Flutter app to TestFlight in the App Store. While the app was running okay on my iPhone 5 and my iPhone Xr when I build directly to my device, when I run it through TestFlight, the Bluetooth never seems to see my devices nor connect to them. (I'm using the flutter_blue_plus module. Note that I am not building a watchOS app.)

Now, I am trying to figure out what is going on and I cannot build to my iPhone Xr. (I can build to my Android device.) Instead, I now get this message:

Launching lib/main.dart on Dan’s iPhone in debug mode...
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
Command line invocation:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -list

User defaults from command line:
IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

2022-05-10 15:01:55.696 xcodebuild[23296:39395199] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore

2022-05-10 15:01:55.696 xcodebuild[23296:39395199] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore

xcodebuild: error: The directory /Users/danielshepard/FlutterProjects/towgo_app/ios contains 2 projects, including multiple projects with the current extension (.xcodeproj). Specify the project to use with the -project option.

Command: /usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun xcodebuild -list

[screen shot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkR01.png)

Can anyone help me figure out why this is not working today?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69661909/processexception-process-exited-abnormally-command-line-invocation-applicati

Comment: I deleted my iOS folder and ran: 
   flutter create .
Then I added back the permissions in info.plist and got it working again.

Answer (score 1):

After many tries I solved in this way:

- Update MacOS
- Update Xcode and command lines tools
- Run `flutter pub upgrade`, `flutter pub get` in the project folder
- Delete podfile.lock in ios folder of the project
- Run `cd ios`, `pod repo update`, `pod install` in the project folder